# Problem with wrongly displayed accented letters

Tags: kubuntu, display, language-support, special-characters, utf-8

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 and I'm having problems with the display of accented letters and some other special characters.

In particular french accented letters are displayed as Cyrillic characters

[image: french accented letters]

and other special (plot axis in log scale in an online editor) symbols are wrongly displayed

[image: plot axis in log scale in an online editor]

This problem arises with different web browsers but also in pdf files (tried to open them with different softwares).

Any hint to solve this problem?

Thanks

Edit 1:
As suggested here is the output  of the command `fc-match -s | head -5`:
[image: output]

Comment: Welcome, what is the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard | grep XKBLAYOUT`?

Comment: Thanks @schrodigerscatcuriosity  for your reply, so the output is:  `XKBLAYOUT="us" `

Comment: My guess is that it is a fonts bug. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `fc-match -s | head -5`

Comment: I suspect something similar too, I just added a screen of  the output.

Comment: The Arimo font is probably something you have installed yourself. Try to uninstall that to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson your comment brought back to my mind that long time ago I installed the Helvetica font by my self, uninstalling it solved my problem! Thank you for the advice

Comment: @SteFx: You may want to put the solution in an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was a manually installed font, uninstalling it solved the problem.
To do it i just removed the fonts files .ttf from the paths `\usr\share\fonts\truetype` and `\usr\local\share\fonts`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why and how a font can affect the rendering of a character ? Till now I'd assumed that this was exclusively down to the languages and keyboards intstalled on the op system . . . Further, if you remove all TTF fonts, will one be able to render online the many commonly used fonts ?